# Изменить возврат от сервиса sms.ru при отправке sms ( команда curl )

Tags: linux, curl, sms, терминал

Сервис sms.ru . При выполнении команды

`curl -d "msg=TEXT" https://sms.ru/sms/send\?api_id=MY_ID\&to=PHONE`

( где `TEXT`- текст sms, который отправляется на телефон, `MY_ID`- ID клиента в сервисе, `PHONE` - номер телефона, на который отправляется sms ) сервис возвращает при каждой отправке sms в терминал служебную информацию о статусе отправки, балансе клиента и т.п. - каждый раз три строки без перевода последней строки, (вот что получается например после двух смс):

`100
201830-1000001
balance=8.13100
201830-1000001
balance=8.13`

у меня на удаленном сервере включен бесконечный скрипт, который отслеживает текущее состояние и при наступлении определенных обстоятельств завершает каждый цикл выполнением вышеуказанной команды и я получаю sms с нужным кодом. Меня не устраивает, что ответы копятся, собственно они мне вообще не нужны там. Как сделать так, чтобы команда выполнялась, но мне в терминал ничего не возвращалось, ну или чтобы возврат был подавлен или как-то невидим?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вечер добрый

```
if [[ ваше условие ]]; then
    # если нужно сделать невидимым по условию
    curl -d "msg=TEXT" https://sms.ru/sms/send\?api_id=MY_ID\&to=PHONE &> /dev/null
fi
```

Если речь идет о *nix и bash оболочке (не указано) stderr и stdout будут перенаправлены в "черную дыру" и не будут захламлять терминал.

Небольшое замечание, вы ничего не "захламляете" если пишите в stdout, вот если пишите в файл то да - используете какое то физическое-виртуальное пространство вашего удаленного сервера

Встречный вопросы:

- скрипт написан на чем? bash/perl/python...
- знакомы ли вы с: /dev/null, >, <, 2 > /dev/null, & > /dev/null

Comment: Спасибо, добавил в свою конструкцию `&> /dev/null`, все работает, ответов нет, что и требовалось. Ответы - 1. bash 2. нет

Comment: @Bl0wfish ну и славно, почитайте про перенаправление потоков в оболочке https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html